# MonoTouch - System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder error

Tags: iphone, .net, json, xamarin.ios, ios5

I am trying to test my app in IPhone (IOS 5) and I get the following error. It works in simulator without any issues.

I am referencing an external library (NewtonSoft.Json.Monotouch.dll) which seems to be using  `System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder`.  Is there a way to overcome this issue? Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Web.Services.dll" -r "/Users/test/application/libraries/Newtonsoft.Json.MonoTouch.dll" -linksdkonly -sdk "5.0" Framework is: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
Copied
 /Users/test/application/bin/iPhone/Release/Unleashed.app
Could not link assemblies: Mono.Linker.ResolutionException: Can not resolve reference: **System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder**

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Alright, I downloaded the latest **NewtonSoft.Json** source code from [link](https://github.com/chrisntr/Newtonsoft.Json), compiled the project and dropped the dll into my project. I still have the same issue. I did figure out the class that refers to **System.Reflection.Emit**. It is DynamicWrapper class in the Utilities folder.

I saw a similar issue posted in another blog [link](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2011-February/002658.html). The responded to the question suggests to set the Liner behavior to "Link all assemblies". Can anyone explain how to set this?

Answer (score 2):

**Newtonsoft.Json.MonoTouch.dll** is known to work with MonoTouch. I've seen/compiled many application using it myself.

It's likely that you are either using an old or a mis-compiled version of assembly (e.g. missing defines). Difficult to say which without knowing it's origin. Try to track a newer version (or edit your question to include where it comes from).

Note: The fact that it works with the simulator is because a different **mscorlib.dll** is used to allow JITting (instead of AOTing) the managed code. This allows the simulator builds to be **much** faster than device builds.

Comment: I think you are right. I am looking at the dll in assembly browser and I see that one of the assembly referenced, "**System.Runtime.Serialization**" is not loaded. Let me try getting a new version. I'll keep you posted of my findings. Thanks for your input

Comment: Latest binary != Latest version. The binaries are more than one year old (Oct 5th 2010) and fixes were committed after that (look at project history). Build it from sources and ensure the MONOTOUCH define is enabled.

Comment: I'm sorry,let me correct myself. I downloaded the source from the link and built the solution and dropped the binary from my build. Still the same issue. I also downloaded the source from [link](https://github.com/chrisntr/Newtonsoft.Json) and tried again.

Comment: Not sure what you downloaded (you link to a web page not source/zip). Ensure that your project options includes MONOTOUCH;NET35;SILVERLIGHT (and DEBUG for your Debug configuration) as this is what the latest commit fixed in the project. Once the SILVERLIGHT define is added then the only place `ModuleBuilder` is used (DynamicWrapper.cs) won't be compiled into the assembly - so the symbol can't be found later when linking your application.

Comment: You can download it either from the "zip" (near the url) link on the top of the page or from the "Downloads as zip" from the downloads section. However, from reading the documentation in [link](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linker#Controlling_the_Linker) , it looks the Linker can not mark for inclusion types and methods that are called through reflection. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is **not** a linker issue (i.e. it's not what's causing the issue here). The linker can **indirectly** fix this when **Link all assemblies** is used because it can eliminate the `DynamicWrapper` type (if unused from your application, YMMV) which cause the **real** issues. The **right** fix is ensuring you're building the assembly with SILVERLIGHT defined (which will exclude `DynamicWrapper` from being compiled).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5376/discussion-between-dk-and-poupou)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of compiling the Newtonsoft.Json.MonoTouch.dll, which did not work for me either, I downloaded the source code from github and added the project to my solution in MonoTouch and compiled the solution. Only then everything worked. (and of course as popou mentioned do not forget the MONOTOUCH;NET35;SILVERLIGHT options.)